# XML '&' character causing problems

Tags: xml

A semi colon character was expected. 
Error processing resource '...

```
<key>SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CNXT_MODEM_PCI_VEN_8086&DEV
```

How can I avoid this error being printed out when viewing my XML file in a browser? It seems to complain because of the '&' character, how do I escape it? thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try escaping it with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 4):

The & character should be escaped as `&amp;`, as per the XML standard. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/xml-escape-characters) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the character entity `&amp;`You will also probably experience issues with the open angle bracket, which needs to be encoded as `&lt;`

Answer (score 3):

How did you create such XML? I bet you created it using string manipulation, as no self-respecting XML API would have produced such invalid XML.

This is why to create XML using XML APIs instead of string APIs.

---

```
var keyElement = new XElement(
    "key", @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CNXT_MODEM_PCI_VEN_8086&DEV");
```

Problem solved.

Comment: +1 for the caveat about creating XML via standard string manipulation

Comment: It may often be useful to create XML by hand. Or indeed edit XML by hand. &amp; is the simple answer, which is not included in this answer.

Comment: XML Can be created by hand, by using an XML-based API, like `XmlWriter` in .NET. This completely avoids this problem, and is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To escape an ampersand:

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and fixed it by using the following:

```
translate(replace(replace(TaskType),'&',' '),' > & < / \ " - ''',' ')
```

it removed all & and hyphen characters. I believe XML does not like those characters.